# Loop between two images

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview, picasso

I want to loop between two images continuously. The first image should be replaced by the second image and the second by the first infinitely.

The code that I have so far is as follows:

```
imageHandler = new Handler();
    imageHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Picasso.with(TokenActivity.this).load(R.drawable.app_icon).into(iconImageView);
        }
    }, 1000);
    imageHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Picasso.with(TokenActivity.this).load(R.drawable.camera_icon).into(iconImageView);
        }
    }, 2000);
```

Here the flip is happening but only once. How do I program it so that it can repeat infinitely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare two runnable :

```
Runnable goToImage2;
Runnable goToImage1 = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
   Picasso.with(TokenActivity.this).load(R.drawable.app_icon).into(iconImageView);
  handler.postDelayed(goToImage2, 2000);
  }
}
goToImage2 = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
   Picasso.with(TokenActivity.this).load(R.drawable.camera_icon).into(iconImageView);
  handler.postDelayed(goToImage1, 2000);
  }
}
```

Then simply launch the first one :

`handler.postDelayed(goToImage1, 0);`

EDIT : If you only need two images, you can also simply use a boolean to know which one to display, and therefore only use one runnable :

`boolean isShowingFirst = true;`

```
Runnable changeImage = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
   Picasso.with(TokenActivity.this).load(isShowingFirst ? R.drawable.camera_icon : R.drawable.app_icon).into(iconImageView);
  isShowingFirst = !isShowingFirst;
  handler.postDelayed(changeImage, 2000);
  }
}
```

And launch it with :

```
handler.postDelayed(changeImage, 0);
```

Comment: Won't the first `runnable` not recognize `goToImage2` in the statement `handler.postDelayed(goToImage2, 2000);`?

Since there is no declaration or definition?

Comment: If that's the case, simply see my edit, declare the 2nd before, but implement it after.

Comment: Only a slight problem with that, since I am accessing the second runnable inside the `run`, it has to be declared final and if it is declared `final`, the error saying might not be initialized is showing up.

Comment: Not if you declare them inside your class instead of in a function

Comment: Ah, my bad. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to simplify the whole thing with a single thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            Picasso.with(TokenActivity.this).load(R.drawable.app_icon).into(iconImageView);

            this.sleep(2000);

            Picasso.with(TokenActivity.this).load(R.drawable.camera_icon).into(iconImageView);


            this.sleep(2000);
        }
    }

}).start();
```

Take this answer with a grain of salt, as it may not be exactly how you want to implement it.